# Weird effect when rotating in vertex shader

Tags: ios, opengl-es

So I am trying to create an instancing effect.  I took a regular rectangle texture shader and added to attributes. BTW My game is a 2d and OpenGL es 2.0

1. An ID to tell it if its the first second or third etc
2. Position offset (So they can move about the screen)
3. Time

Based on the ID I am going to animate rotation based on the rectangles Time, and instance id. I need to do this in the GPU because my cpu overhead is rather high already.

I found a glsl function that claimed to create a rotation matrix based on an angle however it ends up creating a really warped effect.  What I need to do with the matrix is just rotate it by an angle on the 2d screen about the point (0.5, 0.0) (Bottom center) of the rectangle.

However this new rotation function does not work as intended at all, the coordinates are in weird positions, and I am fairly sure that the anchor point isn't at 0.5, 0.0.

Old version (Draws it in the bottom left hand corner, just a plain rectangle) (NOTE: I did not change any of the pos, or tc information in the new version, it merely needs to be rotated)

```
precision highp float;

attribute vec2 pos;
attribute vec2 tc;
attribute float instance;

uniform mat4 matrix;
uniform float time;
uniform vec2 position;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = matrix/* * rotationMatrix(vec3(1.0), 3.14 * instance)*/ * vec4(pos, 1.0, 1.0);
    v_texcoord = tc;
}
```

New Version (Added rotation and position to it)

```
precision highp float;

attribute vec2 pos;
attribute vec2 tc;
attribute float instance;

uniform mat4 matrix;
uniform float time;
uniform vec2 position;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;

mat4 rotationMatrix(vec3 axis, float angle)
{
    axis = normalize(axis);
    float s = sin(angle);
    float c = cos(angle);
    float oc = 1.0 - c;

    return mat4(oc * axis.x * axis.x + c,           oc * axis.x * axis.y - axis.z * s,  oc * axis.z * axis.x + axis.y * s,  0.0,
                oc * axis.x * axis.y + axis.z * s,  oc * axis.y * axis.y + c,           oc * axis.y * axis.z - axis.x * s,  0.0,
                oc * axis.z * axis.x - axis.y * s,  oc * axis.y * axis.z + axis.x * s,  oc * axis.z * axis.z + c,           0.0,
                0.0,                                0.0,                                0.0,                                1.0);
}
void main()
{
    gl_Position = matrix * rotationMatrix(vec3(1.0), 3.14 * instance) * vec4(pos + position, 1.0, 1.0);
    v_texcoord = tc;
}
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

In the formula you found for building the rotation matrix, the vector defining the axis needs to be a unit vector, i.e. it needs to have length 1. That's not the case in your example. When you write `vec3(1.0)`, that corresponds to `vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)`, which is a vector of length `sqrt(3.0)`.

The simple fix is to normalize the vector:

```
normalize(vec3(1.0))
```

or write it as a unit length vector directly:

```
vec3(1.0 / sqrt(3.0))
```

From your description, it actually sounds like you just want to rotate around one of the coordinate axis, so it's not clear why you would want to use `(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)` as the rotation axis.

For example, to rotate point `pos` by `angle` around the z-axis, I wouldn't even bother with building a matrix. Just write the rotation directly as:

```
float c = cos(angle);
float s = sin(angle);
gl_Position = vec4(c * pos.x - s * pos.y, s * pos.x + c * pos.y, pos.zw);
```